# After upgrading jQuery 1.10.2 some problems appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have update from jQuery 1.7.1 to 1.10.2 and now below problem appears in jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js:

```
$("a[data-ajax=true]").live("click", function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    asyncRequest(this, {
        url: this.href,
        type: "GET",
        data: []
    });
});
```

the issue is in live. it says `$("a[data-ajax=true]")` does not accept method or property `live`.

How to solve this? should I upgrade jquer.unobtrusive-ajax.js or something like this?

Comment: `live` is deprecated, use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead

Comment: Dear don't just expect everything to work when you upgrade jquery read the changelog. If you read the live docs you ll see that it was removed in jquery 1.9 http://api.jquery.com/live/ . Use on instead.

Comment: Run the Migrate plugin. https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read the docs please, `live` was removed and replaced with `.on()`

```
$(document).on("click", "a[data-ajax=true]", function (evt) {
```

`document` is the container that houses the dynamic content.

Comment: Sorry, but i am completely new on jQuery. Should I upgrade by modifying the deprecated functions manually in this file rather than upgrading the entire file? Isn't there upgrades of jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js to download from anywhere?

Answer (score 3):

the method .live has been deprecated in version 1.7 and removed later you should use .on

Check the documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/live/

If you are using plugins dependent on live then I would continue to use version 1.7

Answer (score 3):

It's also good to know about the jQuery Migrate Plugin. It's from jQuery itself, and available directly from their [GitHub](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme).

The purpose of the plugin is to "*to simplify the transition from older versions of jQuery. The plugin restores deprecated features and behaviors so that older code will still run properly on jQuery 1.9 and later. Use the uncompressed development version to diagnose compatiblity issues, it will generate warnings on the console that you can use to identify and fix problems.*"

Source: [jQuery download page](http://jquery.com/download/)

Answer (score 1):

use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on("click", "a[data-ajax=true]", function (evt) {
```

See [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) has been [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/) in version 1.7 and removed in 1.9.

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use
>   .delegate() in preference to .live().